# why is "if" function always out put same result

Tags: python-3.x

why the different input always shows the same result

```
is_male=input("are you male or female?\n")
is_tall=input("are you tall?(Y/N)\n")
male=True
female=False
Y=True
N=False
if is_male and is_tall:
    print("you are a tall male")
elif is_male and not(is_tall):
    print("you are a short male")
elif not(is_male) and is_tall:
    print("you are tall female")
else:
    print("you are short female")
```

when i tried to input "female" and "N" , and the result always show "you are a tall male", how can i fix this?

Comment: You have to translate your input to the desired bool - e.g. translate the string ``"N"`` to ``False``. At the moment, you test if *strings* are true which is always the case unless they are empty. Defining ``N = False`` only means the *name* ``N`` is False, not the *string* ``"N"``.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Stores input in is_male
is_male=input("are you male or female?\n")
# Stores input in is_tall
is_tall=input("are you tall?(Y/N)\n")
# Sets a variable male as True
male=True
# Sets a variable female as False
female=False
# Sets variable Y as True
Y=True
# Sets variable N as False
N=False
# Checks is the string is_male is true and is_tall is true, any string is always True
if is_male and is_tall:
    print("you are a tall male")
elif is_male and not(is_tall):
    print("you are a short male")
elif not(is_male) and is_tall:
    print("you are tall female")
else:
    print("you are short female")
```

As explained in the code above, a string is evaluated as True unless it is "". Therefore in your code the first condition will always evaluate to true.

All the variable assignments that you are doing is useless.

```
# Stores input in is_male
is_male=input("are you male or female?\n")
# Stores input in is_tall
is_tall=input("are you tall?(Y/N)\n")

if is_male == 'Y':
    # Code to handle male.
else:
    # Code to handle female.
```

You should fill in the code to handle tall for the both cases as an exercise.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it seem very beginner's problem, I am also a beginner, haha

Comment: That's fine, we have all been there.

Answer (score 0):

Your are assigning string value in all variables
So you have to do like this:

````
is_male=input("are you male or female?\n")
is_tall=input("are you tall?(Y/N)\n")


if is_male == 'Male' and is_tall == 'Y' 
   print("you are a tall male")
elif ................ ```
````